# Reference/link to object in javascript using xml

Tags: javascript, xml, reference, hyperlink

Take an xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<events>
    <event>
        <start></start>
        <duration></duration>
        <begin>{somecallback}</begin>
        <complete>{someclass.someproperty = somevalue;}</complete>
    </event>
</events>
```

- I need to be able to parse the xml and execute the string versions of javascript code. I know javascript has an eval function, but I need to know if eval can act on the above `begin` and `complete` or if there is an easier way to do this.

Both `begin` and `complete` need to either directly access a callback (without parameters), or directly set a value to a property belonging to a class. I'm sure I can `eval()` a callback, but I am unsure how to proceed with directly setting property values in this manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval` will operate on objects that are in scope as expected:

```
js> var o = {}
js> eval('o.p = 1')
1
js> o.p
1
```

What you should consider is if you need the flexibility of `eval` for what you are doing. Can `somecallback` be a property of an object? If so, you can call `o[fn]()` where `fn` is "somecallback," for instance. This is much safer than using `eval`. Your `<complete>` section is too vague for me to recommend a way to avoid `eval` in the second case however.